# Replace missing values of numerical features with unique numbers

Tags: missing-data

Let's suppose that I have a dataset with 5 numerical features of which each of them has some missing values and all of them have only non negative values.

Some suggested ways to deal with missing data are:

1. Remove the rows which have even one missing value
2. Impute the missing values

I do not prefer (1) because then you miss some valuable information from the rest of the features for these rows.

I do not prefer (2) because in general (it depends on the application) it introduces quite a lot of noise in the data.

What I am thinking is to:
 3. Replace the missing values with a unique value (eg -1 or -999)

As I said, in my example the features have only non-negative numbers so values such as -1 or -999 will be only encountered by the algorithm for missing data.

What are your thoughts on (3)?

What are the advantages and disadvantages of this approach?

Answer (score 2):

This depends on the exact learning algorithm which is used, but most of the time numerical values are treated... numerically.

It's easy to see with the case of linear regression: let's say a feature has values between 0 and 100, but with a few missing values. Now replace missing values with -999: the coefficient learned for this feature will be completely different and based on  meaningless indications, so the performance will decrease.

This idea might work in the case where the numerical values are 'binned' into several classes, i.e. transformed into ordinal/categorical variables.

But the best way to use such values is to use an algorithm and framework which can deal with missing values in the first place.

Comment: Thank you for your reply(upvote). Yes, I agree that it will be probably a quite problematic for linear models but what about non-linear models (eg random forest)? Will it be relatively ok?

Comment: In any case, how to handle missing values is a quite big topic and I have not found any better way to do this (I am not in favor of imputations).

Comment: @PoeteMaudit technically your approach is a kind of imputation. Unfortunately it's annoyingly difficult to find information about how a particular implementation of an algorithm treats missing values, but many of them are able to handle missing values in a smart way. That's the case for (some?) decision trees implementations. See for example how different algorithms deal with missing values in Weka here: https://weka.8497.n7.nabble.com/Missing-values-in-different-classifiers-td33738.html

Comment: imputation->"the assignment of a value to something by inference from the value of the products or processes to which it contributes" . It is no inference (at least based on the value of other features) what I do by assigning a constant but based on the (missing) value of the feature itself but ok I see your point.

Comment: At the main question now, my question was about non-linear models (eg random forests) in general. So I would like to know your opinion on them too (and not only about specific implementations of them) :) . Personally, I use the standard implementation of random forest of SkLearn in any case.

Comment: For example, here (https://towardsdatascience.com/handling-missing-values-in-machine-learning-part-1-dda69d4f88ca) it says: "The downside is that performance of linear models can suffer." and hence it implies that the performance of non-linear models does not?

Comment: It's clear that this method will introduce a bias with linear models (or any model which relies on numerical regression). But as far as I know there's no general answer for non-linear models, since there are many different kinds with different properties. In any case a model which knows how to deal with missing values should accept "NA" or "NaN" values as part of the format: using a specific value like -999 is going to be interpreted as a regular value, in this case the only way to know if it works would be to do many different tests with/without the instances which contain missing values.

Comment: Hm, do not take it the wrong way please but your answer do not satisfies me much. To start with the link the link above (as other ones) implies that there is a general answer for non-linear model (excluding very specific/special implementations of it). Secondly, I am not exactly talking about missing values but about out of the range values eg -999 (after replacing missing values). Thirdly, I talked specifically, about the RandomForestClassifier of SkLearn so even if you are not sure about a general answer then at least you could try to come up with one for this specific one.

Comment: If the official doc (https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.ensemble.RandomForestClassifier.html) doesn't give any info about it, I can't guess the answer for this specific implementation of random forest. You can analyze the source code if you want: https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn

Comment: Haha yes I knew all that. In any case, thank you for time. If I draw any conclusion is that probably non-linear models are not affected that much from replacing missing values with a constant since I have not found any posts mentioning sth different.